# Why yaml convert "1:2" to number 62?

Tags: javascript, yaml

This segment of yaml

```yaml
---
a: 1:2
```

is converted to this json

```json
{
  "a": 62
}
```

in https://yamlvalidator.com/

What happened here? Is it invalid?

Comment: See https://yaml.org/type/float.html

Comment: `1:2` should be a string. I.e. `"1:2"`